# IntelliJ terminal log does not show fully

Tags: logging, intellij-idea, terminal

The log is seem stop at a certain point like this:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to make it shows full line?

Comment: What exactly is displayed on your screenshot? Is that the output of a run configuration, a log console, or something else entirely? What process are you running?

Comment: It is a console log under "terminal" tab.

Comment: I had the same problem. Did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Because of logging mechanism is a Asynchronous -> it will appear on some parallel logging related Thread ;)) or for pagination mechanism Intellij shows logs optimally ;))  if do you want to locate log files

just press cmd(cntrl on windows)+shift+a -> "Show log in File Manager" -> you can find it in a folder.

May be this is helpful : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files